# Expected expression before ',' token reverseString(++s*, --sSize);

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote my function to print a string in reverse order, but it keeps showing an error:

> `expected expression before ',' token  reverseString(++s*, --sSize);`

Code snippet:

```
void reverseString(char* s, int sSize){
    /* If the size haven't reach 0, keeps deducting */
    if (sSize != 0) {
        reverseString(++s*, --sSize);
    }

    print *s;
}
```

How should I fix this properly?

Comment: Just remove that '*'..

Comment: You probably should write just `s + 1`.

Comment: And `print *s` is not valid C code either. Perhaps you want `printf("%s\n", s)`

Comment: The `*` in `++s*` can only be a multiplication symbol, and the compiler is objecting that there is nothing on the RHS of the `*`.  You can use `*++s` and `++*s` (with different effects), but in this case, `s + 1` is most likely what you want.  The function is misnamed; it prints the string in reverse without reversing the string.

Comment: I suggest to change the title to "Where can I learn C/C++?" It seems to be all about pointer syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like that:

```
void printReversedString(const char* s, size_t length) {
    if (length != 0)
        printReversedString(s + 1, --length);

    putchar(*s);
}
```